# python ffmpeg moov atom not found Invalid data when processing input

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a progress that records the screen, and audio from a microphone, and then combines the video and audio recording (.mp4 and .wav) into one mkv file.

I am using python 3.6 and ffmpeg to achieve this aim. For short videos (<20 sec.) it works, but for longer recordings it presents the following error message:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55abb3a52540] moov atom not found
tmp/tmp_0.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Full output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (GCC)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin -- 
datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg -- 
incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man -- 
arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp, 
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp- 
buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat- 
hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' --extra- 
ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' -- 
extra-cflags='-I/usr/include/nvenc ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb -- 
enable- 
libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib 
--disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt -- 
enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable- 
libcdio --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi -- 
enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable- 
opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable- 
libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex -- 
enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable- libvidstab - 
-enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid -- 
enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads -- 
disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable- 
stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[wav @ 0x55abb3a0b880] Ignoring maximum wav data size, file may be invalid
[wav @ 0x55abb3a0b880] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be 
inaccurate
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'tmp/tmp_0.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:21.97, bitrate: 768 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_mulaw ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), 48000 Hz, 
stereo, s16, 768 kb/s
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55abb3a52540] moov atom not found
tmp/tmp_0.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The python file (ffmpeg.py) is as follows. The class, AV_COMPILE, is not yet complete, held up by the aforementioned error, and therefore still uses the initial test files as defaults. But otherwise it ought to work:

```
import os, time, glob

TMP_DIR = "tmp"
DISPLAY = os.environ['DISPLAY']
EXT = {
    'Video':'mp4',
    'Audio':'wav',
    'AV':'mkv',
}

class ffmpegVideo:

    FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg"
    AUDIO = False

    def __init__(self, fps = 30, audio = True):
    global TMP_DIR, DISPLAY, EXT

    self.fps = fps

    if audio:
        self.AUDIO = True

    self.video_filename = self.unique_filename()

    self.command = [ self.FFMPEG_BIN,
        '-video_size', '1920x1080',
        '-framerate', str(fps),
        '-f', 'x11grab',
        '-i', DISPLAY,
        '-vcodec', 'libx264',
        '-qp', '0',
        '-preset', 'ultrafast',
        '-y', TMP_DIR + '/' + self.video_filename
    ]

def start(self):
    import threading as th

    thread = th.Thread(target=self.record)
    thread.start()

def record(self):
    import subprocess as sp

    self.pipe = sp.Popen(self.command, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    if self.AUDIO:
        ffmpegAudio().start()

def stop(self):
    self.pipe.terminate()

def unique_filename(self):
    global TMP_DIR, EXT

    i = 0

    while os.path.exists((TMP_DIR + '/' + 'tmp_%s.%s') % (i, EXT['Video'])):
        i += 1

    return ('tmp_%s.%s') % (i, EXT['Video'])

class ffmpegAudio:

    FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg"

    def __init__(self):

        self.audio_filename = self.unique_filename()

        self.command = [ self.FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-f', 'pulse',
            '-ac', '2',
            '-ar', '48000',
            '-i', 'default',
           '-acodec', 'pcm_mulaw',
           '-y', TMP_DIR + '/' + self.audio_filename
        ]

    def start(self):
        import threading as th

        au_thread = th.Thread(target=self.record)
        au_thread.start()

    def record(self):
         import subprocess as sp

        self.pipe = sp.Popen(self.command, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    def stop(self):
        self.pipe.terminate()

    def unique_filename(self):
        global TMP_DIR, EXT

        i = 0

        while os.path.exists((TMP_DIR + '/' + 'tmp_%s.%s') % (i, EXT['Audio'])):
        i += 1

        return ('tmp_%s.%s') % (i, EXT['Audio'])

class AV_COMPILE:

    def __init__(self, au_in = TMP_DIR + '/' + 'out1.wav', vd_in = 
TMP_DIR + '/' + 'test4.mp4', out = TMP_DIR + '/' + 'av.mkv'):
        import subprocess as sp

        au_in = min(glob.iglob(TMP_DIR + '/*.wav'), key=os.path.getctime)
        vd_in = min(glob.iglob(TMP_DIR + '/*.mp4'), key=os.path.getctime)

        self.command = ('ffmpeg -i %s  -r 30 -i %s -shortest -c:a aac -c:v copy %s') % (au_in, vd_in, out)
        sp.call(self.command, shell=True)
```

I would be grateful for any assistance you could provide in understanding why this happens and how to solve the error. Also, I am happy to receive any other tips on how to improve this code, or any other problems anyone might notice.

**EDIT:**
I now believe that the reason for this error in longer videos, and occasionally shorter, is that the program is proceeding to attempt to compile the av output whether or not it has finished compiling the original video file. I tested a `time.sleep(10)` function to delay AV_COMPILE, and this seems to work.

However, as video files get larger, obviously the delay needs to be adjusted. So I should like to know how I can separately check the integrity of the video file and determine that it is safe to proceed to the next step.

Comment: Consider sharing your mp4 file - otherwise I could only guess.

Comment: I have made the video available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rju9fox2k5pdqc1/tmp_4.mp4?dl=0

Comment: tmp_4.mp4 is fine and only 4 seconds long. Did you send the correct file?

Comment: Sorry, I have now made a 30 sec. clip available: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cdo2sofnn423q86/tmp_0.mp4?dl=0. The problem is that, whilst it plays by itself, the error mentioned above appears when I attempt to run the ffmpeg code combining tmp_0.mp4 and tmp_0.wav.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding `moov atom not found` well I checked your file and the atom is there, but at the back-end of your file (but it needs to be available first before the rest of the MP4 data can be processed).

MP4 containers are structured in such a way that the a/v data is stored without frame headers and the Moov atom is a table, listing the byte positions and byte lengths for each a/v frame. The Moov atom can only exist after recording is complete when the relevant metadata can now be created for the stored data.

This is why fragmented MP4 was introduced.

**Solution:**

Don't put your a/v data into an MP4 then transfer same a/v out of the MP4 into a MKV container. I suspect you went with `MP4` container setting in order to get output (picture) encoded with H.264 video codec?

I don't use Python but try setting:

```
'Video':'libx264',
'Audio':'wav',
'AV':'mkv',
```